# Autocomplete not sending the right converter value if typed manually

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Here are some points :

1. I have a primefaces autocomplete example that makes use of a POJO with a custom converter.
2. Im returning a UUID string for the getAsString in the converter.
3. The string value from the converter is sent fine if i choose the value from the autocomplete dropdown dialog, either by keyboard or mouse click.
4. But when i type the value myself without choosing from the autocomplete dropdown dialog, or just pasted the value into the text field, the **Validation Error: Value is required**. error will happen.
5. I notice this error happens because the value sent to the server side is not the string generated by my converter, but the value typed itself.

---

Using firebug shows this in action.

This is when the i choose the value from autocomplete dropdown dialog, either by keyboard or mouseclick, we can notice the value is in the UUID format, which is returned by my pojo converter :

```
<input aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" role="textbox" 
  autocomplete="off" id="DetailDialogForm:Bagian_input" 
  name="DetailDialogForm:Bagian_input" value="PERSO" 
  class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-autocomplete-input" 
  type="text">
<input id="DetailDialogForm:Bagian_hinput" 
  name="DetailDialogForm:Bagian_hinput" 
  value="b0019ab2-28c3-451a-90f6-62a6941ffcaa" type="hidden">
```

---

This is when the i typed or pasted the value, we can notice the value is exactly what i typed, which is NOT returned by my pojo converter :

```
<input aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" 
  role="textbox" autocomplete="off" id="DetailDialogForm:Bagian_input" 
  name="DetailDialogForm:Bagian_input" value="PERSO" 
  class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-autocomplete-input" 
  type="text">
<input id="DetailDialogForm:Bagian_hinput" 
  name="DetailDialogForm:Bagian_hinput" value="PERSO" type="hidden">
```

---

Is this the intended behaviour of this element ?

---

Im using tomcat 7, and these are my dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4-b09</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

Please share your thoughts, thank you !

---

UPDATE

---

This is the JSF excerpt :

```
<p:autoComplete id="Bagian" label="Bagian yang di limpahkan"
    value="#{tInputBean.activeDetail.map['department']}"
    completeMethod="#{tInputBean.filterDepartment}" var="department"
    itemLabel="#{department.map['departmentName']}"
    itemValue="#{department}" converter="genericConverter"
    forceSelection="true" required="true" />
```

And the converter is available at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268179/generic-jsf-entity-converter), in BalusC's answer on EntityConverter

---

Answer (score 0):

Would you post your .xhtml, i need to check the <p:autoComplete />

Please check:

1. do you have added <p:autoComplete> attribute forceSelection
2. When user select on list of suggestions given by autoComplete, it should use use selectListener, and update partial view using onSelectUpdate
3. check if there is <p:ajax/> inside <p:autoComplete/>, try to remove it

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated my original post. But to make it short, #1 : yes, #2 : im not trying to update anything after selecting from the autocomplete, #3 : `no p:ajax`