# JSF Entityconverter ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, jsf

I'm using a generic entity converter in my Project.
I've noticed that sometimes the converter throws a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`
There is also a 4 years old [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819014/jsf-generic-entity-converter-is-not-threadsafe) which has no answer.

I tried to use `Iterator` instead of a plain `for-loop` but it didn't helped.

Is there a way to create a thread-safe converter?

```
@FacesConverter(value = "entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

    private static Map<Object, String> entities = new WeakHashMap<Object, String>();

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
        synchronized (entities) {
            if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                entities.put(entity, uuid);
                return uuid;
            } else {
                return entities.get(entity);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {

        Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, String>> tempIt = entities.entrySet().iterator();
        while (tempIt.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Object, String> nextObj = tempIt.next();
            if (nextObj.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
                return nextObj.getKey();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the body of `getAsObject` in a block synchronized on `entities`, as in the other method.

Comment: Thanks alot! I don't know why I didn't tried that first!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve it is to use Java's [ConcurrentMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) in order to guarantee thread-safety. In a one-liner:

```
private static ConcurrentMap<Object, String> entities = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
    return entities.putIfAbsent(entity, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}
```

Starting from Java 8, you could also take advantage from [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), which will only calculate the UUID if the key is absent:

```
return entities.putIfAbsent(entity, 
    entities.computeIfAbsent(k -> UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
```

Or even enhance it with [Guava's caching utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802420/1199132), if you want to keep weak references.

Comment: It would be better to use `computeIfAbsent`, so you only compute a new uuid when necessary.