# PrimeFaces p:dataList issues error "Property 'ime' not found on type java.lang.String"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datalist

I want to make Checkbox menu and display data in dataList. Here is my xhtml:

```
<h:form>
 <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
    <h:outputLabel for="menu" value="Demonstratori :" />
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="menu" value="#{nastavnik.odabraniDemonstratori}" label="Demonstratori:"
                                  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px">
        <f:selectItems value="#{nastavnik.sviDemonstratori}" var="demons" itemLabel="#{demons.ime} #{demons.prezime}" itemValue="#{demons}" />
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
    <p:commandLink value="Submit" update="display" />
 </h:panelGrid>

    <p:outputPanel id="display" style="width:250px;padding-left:5px;margin-top:10px">
        <p:dataList value="#{nastavnik.odabraniDemonstratori}" var="d" type="ordered" emptyMessage="Nema odabranih demonstratora">
             #{d.ime}"
        </p:dataList>
   </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Here is important code from Nastavnik bean :

```
private ArrayList<Demonstrator> odabraniDemonstratori;
public void setOdabraniDemonstratori(ArrayList<Demonstrator> odabraniDemonstratori) {
    this.odabraniDemonstratori = odabraniDemonstratori;
}


public ArrayList<Demonstrator> getOdabraniDemonstratori() {
    return odabraniDemonstratori;
}
```

Demonstrator bean has property `ime`. Everything works good, but when I try to show data in dataList with `#{d.ime}`, I am getting this error:

```
/unoslabvezbe.xhtml @84,49 value="#{d.ime}": Property 'ime' not found on type java.lang.String
```

`d` property is type Demonstrator not String. Any help ?

Comment: Is `Demonstrator` a public class?

Comment: Yes its hibernate bean :@Entity
public class Demonstrator extends Korisnik

Comment: Does it work with a simpler example? e.g. Just return an `ArrayList<String>`?  This is just a debugging suggestion, not a "solution".

Comment: When i write just #{d} it calls toString() method on Demonstrator so i know i have there a Demonstrator object not String, but when i write #{d.ime} he calls getIme() on String...

Comment: Does the error still occur if you take out the entire `p:selectCheckboxMenu`? I know you say the error message is complaining about `#{d.ime}`, but after what Mathieu is saying below I would like to rule it out.

Comment: Mathieu was right, p:selectCheckboxMenu was a problem...

Comment: If he was exactly right and it was the converter, mark his answer as correct to help others know that it is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a selection component (such as `p:selectCheckboxMenu` or `p:pickList`), you need a converter to handle complex (= not a simple String) Java objects as values of `f:selectItems`. A converter will serialize and deserialize your entity `Demonstrator`.

Therefore you need to add the `converter` attribute for your `p:selectCheckboxMenu` and reference your own converter, or even better, use the ready-to-use `SelectItemsConverter` ([showcase link](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter)) provided by [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/), a great utility library for JSF developers (installation is straightforward: add the .jar file or add a new dependency in Maven).

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="menu" value="#{nastavnik.odabraniDemonstratori}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" label="Demonstratori:" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px">
    <f:selectItems value="#{nastavnik.sviDemonstratori}" var="demons" itemLabel="#{demons.ime} #{demons.prezime}" itemValue="#{demons}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

---

Note: To learn more about designing your own converter (not the way to go):

- [Generic JSF entity converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268179/generic-jsf-entity-converter)
- [How to write a custom converter for <p:pickList>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621251/how-to-write-a-custom-converter-when-working-with-primefaces-components-that-co)
- [Arguments against a generic JSF object converter with a static WeakHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186849/arguments-against-a-generic-jsf-object-converter-with-a-static-weakhashmap)

Comment: That's not the case here, Mathieu. You can access the basic properties (String, Integer, etc.) of a complex object without writing a converter for the complex object. I have just tested this locally using a `p:dataList`, and it works as expected.

Comment: It's not about accessing properties of complex objects in `p:dataList` but about setting these objects (that will, indeed, be displayed in a `p:dataList` component) thanks to a selection component (`p:selectCheckboxMenu` in that case)

Comment: That's a good point, Mathieu, but the error message the OP posted is complaining about `"{d.ime}`, which is an expression he has used outside of the `p:selectCheckboxMenu`. Hmm, but I guess the lack of converter could be causing this, couldn't it? If the default converter treats it as a String, then maybe the lack of converter is causing this error message. (I cannot remove my downvote unless you edit your answer.)

Comment: @DavidS Yeah, you got it!